# fetch content between _(" ") in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to fetch all the strings between _(" ") from my file.

How may i fetch that?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you wanting strings within a pair of double quotes, or within a pair of double quotes surrounded by parentheses?

Comment: What should happen if there are nested `_(" ")`s, like `foo _("bar _("baz")")`?

Comment: @sepp2k: in general, you should answer a regex question, rather than just complain about nesting (unless it's really obvious that nesting is a problem). You can always mention a caveat that it doesn't work if the string is nested, but it's rude to just refuse outright to answer the question. In this case, it's conventional to use `_()` to all `gettext` on a string, so I assume what he's trying to do is scan a file to find all of the strings that need to be localized -- and they're unlikely to include nesting because `_("baz")` isn't a word in any human language I know of.

Comment: @Ken Bloom That exactly i want it.

Comment: @Ken: I did not refuse anything, I asked for clarification. Obviously the answer to the question is different depending on how he wants to handle the nested case. And yes, the fact that this is about gettext makes it obvious that the nested case does not matter, but I don't think not realizing that this is about gettext makes me rude.

Comment: @sepp2k: in my view -- always assume that a Regexp question can be answered with a Regexp unless there are *clear* reasons to assume otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no quotation marks nested within the string you're looking for, you want to load the file into a string

```
str=File.read("/path/to/file")
```

Then scan the string using a regular expression. The following regular expression should do the trick. It looks for the characters `_("` (the open parentheses here is escaped, because parentheses have a special meaning in regular expressions). The next parentheses starts a capturing group (so that the text of the string will be stored in the special variable `$1`. Then it finds a string of consecutive characters until the first quotation mark. Then it ends the capturing group (with an unescaped close parentheses) looks for a `")` to finish the expression.

```
/_\("([^"]*)"\)/
```

To use it

```
str.scan( /_\("([^"]*)"\)/ ) do
  puts $1
end
```